# Pandas - Merge two dataframes and unify set of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given two separate dataframes I'm looking to merge them and unify a set of their joined columns.

Example:

```
In[1]: df1

Out[1]: 
   a_id     a_time a_val
0     1  100000000     a
1     2  200000000     b
2     3  300000000     c

In[10]: df2

Out[10]: 
   b_id     b_time b_val
0     1  100000000     d
1     2  150000000     e
2     3  350000000     f
```

The resulting dataframe I'm looking for is the following

```
   id       time val
0   1  100000000   a
1   1  100000000   d
2   2  150000000   e
3   2  200000000   b
4   3  300000000   c
5   3  350000000   f
```

Assuming all IDs are present on both tables, the result should be of length `len(df1) + len(df2)`.

I was looking at some results using `.stack()` but I couldn't really figure out how to make it work on when merging two tables.

Notice the time could be the same, or could be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need same columns in both `df` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
cols = ['id', 'time', 'val']
df1.columns = cols
df2.columns = cols

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
   id       time val
0   1  100000000   a
1   1  100000000   d
2   2  200000000   b
3   2  150000000   e
4   3  300000000   c
5   3  350000000   f
```

Comment: Baah... was looking so hard at `.stack()` I missed the most simple solution. Thanks!

Comment: accept the solution @bluesummers if u have solved u r problem

Answer (score 3):

you can also do it this way:

```
In [45]: pd.concat([df.rename(columns=lambda x: re.sub(r'.*?_',' ',x))
                    for df in [df1,df2]],
                   ignore_index=True)
Out[45]:
    id       time  val
0    1  100000000    a
1    2  200000000    b
2    3  300000000    c
3    1  100000000    d
4    2  150000000    e
5    3  350000000    f
```